# MacBook Pro 2019 Not Charging From Powerbank

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

I have 30000mAh power bank that I bought to use to charge my MacBook Pro 2019. But I found out that it's not working. My computer says: Power Source: Power Adapter; Battery is Not Charging.

Is this a problem?

Comment: You might need to link to your product. Milliamp-hours is a “volume” or “capacity” and not a discharge rate. We need to know how much of that charge it can provide in a set time period to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it’s a problem if you depend on this to charge your Mac at full speed, no it’s no problem if you are patient and use this to recharge while the Mac is off or sleeping. Even an idle Mac can take more power than some chargers provide when they are working correctly.

> Power Source: Power Adapter; Battery is Not Charging

This means a power source is connected but it is not providing sufficient wattage to charge the battery.

The wattage required by using the computer is more than the wattage provided by the power supply, so the battery will continue to discharge.

Turn off the laptop to reduce the wattage required to run it so the internal battery charges, or buy a power bank which provides a higher wattage.

The milliamp hours of the power bank tells you how much charge the bank can store, not how quickly it can deliver it. Look at the wattage of the power bank and compare it to the 96W wall adapter your MacBook Pro came with. [Apple increased the wattage of the wall adapter from 87W to 96W for the 2019 MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201700) to keep up with the demands of the laptop — your power bank won't be able to match this, but with extremely light usage (or powered off) a high wattage power bank can still charge MacBook.

Comment: My power bank says that it's 3.7V 111WH

Comment: @Arina Watt-hours is capacity, look for watts.

Comment: it doesn't says(